How to create CMS from an existing signature (generated by a Remote Signing Service)?
I created a CMS signature using an existing signature generated by a Remote Signing Service.
Before that, I hashed the message to be signed with SHA256, then I sent it to the Remote Signing Service and received a signature. I used this signature to create a CMS signature, resulting in a p7m file.
Here is the code I used to accomplish this:
public static void signMessage() {
    String messageToBeSign = "It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.";
    byte[] dataToSign = messageToBeSign.getBytes();
    
    // Log hashed data to send it to Remote Signing Service
    // MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    // byte[] hashedData = digest.digest(dataToSign);
    // System.out.println(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(hashedData));

    // Load signature recieved from Remote Signing Service
    byte[] remoteSignature = Base64.getDecoder().decode(remoteSignatureBase64String);
    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

    // Load signing certificate
    byte[] certBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64CertChain[0]);
    X509CertificateHolder certHolder = new X509CertificateHolder(certBytes);

    DigestCalculatorProvider digestCalculatorProvider = new JcaDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder().build();
    JcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder signerInfoGenBuilder = new JcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder(digestCalculatorProvider);
    ContentSigner contentSigner = new PrecomputedSigner(remoteSignature);
    SignerInfoGenerator signerInfoGenerator = signerInfoGenBuilder.build(contentSigner, certHolder);

    // Load full certificate chain
    List&amp;lt;X509CertificateHolder&amp;gt; certChain = new ArrayList&amp;lt;&amp;gt;();
    for (String base64Cert : base64CertChain) {
        certChain.add(new X509CertificateHolder(Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64Cert)));
    }
    Store certStore = new JcaCertStore(certChain);
    
    CMSSignedDataGenerator generator = new CMSSignedDataGenerator();
    generator.addSignerInfoGenerator(signerInfoGenerator);
    generator.addCertificates(certStore);

    CMSProcessableByteArray cmsData = new CMSProcessableByteArray(dataToSign);
    CMSSignedData signedData = generator.generate(cmsData, true);
    byte[] p7m = signedData.getEncoded();
    
    try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(signedFileOutput)) {
        fos.write(p7m);
    }
    
    System.out.println("Successfully create a new signature to the .p7m file!");
}

//Helper class to handle the precomputed signature from the Remote Signing Service
class PrecomputedSigner implements ContentSigner {
    private final byte[] signature;

    public PrecomputedSigner(byte[] signature) {
        this.signature = signature;
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] getSignature() {
        return signature;
    }

    @Override
    public AlgorithmIdentifier getAlgorithmIdentifier() {
       return new AlgorithmIdentifier(PKCSObjectIdentifiers.sha256WithRSAEncryption);
    }

    @Override
    public OutputStream getOutputStream() {
        return new ByteArrayOutputStream(); // Not used since the signature is precomputed
    }
}

I successfully created a p7m file containing the signature and proceeded to verify it using the DSS Demonstration WebApp. However, I encountered some errors during the verification process.

The signature is not intact!
The signed attribute: 'signing-certificate' is absent!

Validation results
What did I do wrong? How can I make it right?
Thank you so much for taking the time to read and consider the question. It really means a lot to me!

CMS/PKCS7 signatures are (normally) not computed directly on the data, although the very earliest versions did so and the option still exists for backward compatibility. Instead the usual method -- and the default for BouncyCastle -- is that 'signedAttributes' are constructed, including among other things the hash of the data, and the publickey signature is computed using a hash of (a specific encoding of) the signedAttributes. See the RFC sections 5.4 through 5.6 or my answer over on crypto.
Thus the signature you pre-computed and jammed into a dummy provider is on completely wrong data, and thus the wrong signature.
BouncyCastle can still create an old-style 'direct' signature but most modern systems don't want and won't accept it -- especially since the verifier result you show demands a specific signedAttribute for signingCertificate which is common though not required by CMS and not the default for BouncyCastle -- see 2634 or more up-to-date (and probably more likely) 5035. To correctly create an indirect or with-attributes signature you need a provider that intercepts the data generated by BouncyCastle and signs that using the remote system, not the original message data:

Adding external PKCS1 byte array and Certificate to CMS container with Java
PDFBox - Signing a PDF using an external service (document has been altered or corrupted)

To add attributes in signedAttributes, such as signingCertificate (or v2?) in your case, see:

Adding Signing certificate as signed attributes in CMS
Add signed/authenticated attributes to CMS signature using BouncyCastle  (almost)

